# How to get PropertyNames of Invoke-Sqlcmd command

Tags: powershell

Normally I can get the PropertyNames of a `PSObject` like this:

```
$xy.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

However, I get a `PSObject` from a `Invoke-Sqlcmd` like this:

```
$GetQueryNormeinsatz = "SELECT ARTIKEL_NR as ArtNo, SMW1 as NameDE, SMN2 as BreiteVon FROM SOMEWHERE
$GetDataNormeinsatz = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionLogik -Query $GetQueryNormeinsatz
```

Now when I do this:

```
$GetDataNormeinsatz.PSObject.Properties | select -expand Name
```

I would expect it to return

```
ArtNo
NameDE
BreiteVon
```

However, it returns this:

```
Count
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot
IsReadOnly
IsFixedSize
IsSynchronized
```

Why? And how can I get my desired ouput? Thx!

Comment: What do you get from just `$GetDataNormeinsatz`?

Comment: Have you tried `$GetDataNormeinsatz | Get-member`

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I get the whole Object returned, with correct Propertynames and correct Values. Basically the SQL Values I'm after

Comment: @Sid good call, `$GetDataNormeinsatz | gm | ? Membertype -eq Property | select -expand Name` returned my correct PropertyNames. Do you know why the other command I wrote in the question didn't work?

Comment: I think you don't need the `.PSObject.Properties` part. What do you get with `$GetDataNormeinsatz | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` ?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent a whole lot of errors :-). Because it can't find a Name Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property listing suggests that `$GetDataNormeinsatz` is an *array*, not a single custom object.

Taking advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) you could therefore simply write:

```sh
$GetDataNormeinsatz.Name
```

This will return the `.Name` property values of all the *elements* in your `$GetDataNormeinsatz` array.

If (some of) these elements do not have a `.Name` property, you'll get a `$null` value for each element that doesn't, by default; if `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect, a statement-terminating error occurs ("The property '...'' cannot be found on this object").

To inspect the types of your array elements, use the following:

```sh
$GetDataNormeinsatz | % GetType
```

To see the *properties* of these types too, use:

```sh
$GetDataNormeinsatz | Get-Member -Type Properties
```

Comment: @SimonS: This means that the array elements don't have `.Name` properties - please see my update.